# How to make if-elif-else statement in python more space-saving?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a lot of if-elif-else statements in my code

```
if message == '0' or message == '3' or message == '5' or message == '7':
   ...
elif message == '1' or message == '2' or message == '4' or message == '6' or message == '8':
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Is it possible to format this in a more space-saving way?

I tried it this way:

```
if message == '0' or '3' or '5' or '7':
   ...
elif message == '1' or '2' or '4' or '6' or '8':
   ...
else:
   ...
```

But without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if message in ("0", "3", "5", "7"):
    ...
elif message in ...
```

would be one way.

If `message` is always one character long, you could also use

```
if message in "0357":
    ....
```

But this would also be true if `message == "35"`, therefore the warning.

---

(EDIT)

A short explanation why your approach wasn't working:

```
if message == '0' or '3' or '5' or '7':
```

is interpreted as

```
if (message == '0') or '3' or '5' or '7':
```

and therefore *always* succeeds because `'3'` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if message in '0357' :
    ...
elif message in '12468' :
    ...
else:
    ...
```

In a more global way :

```
if value in [elem0, elem1, ... ]:
    ...
```